# How can I select by rows instead of individual cells in QTableView in PyQt?

Tags: pyqt, selection, qtableview

In the sample code below (heavily influenced from [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/12/pyqt-43-qtableview-qabstracttablemodel/)), I want the entire row of the clicked cell to be selected instead of the individual cell. How can I change the code to incorporate that?

```
import re
import operator
import os
import sys
import sqlite3
import cookies
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        # data
        self.tabledata = [('apple', 'red', 'small'),
                          ('apple', 'red', 'medium'),
                          ('apple', 'green', 'small'),
                          ('banana', 'yellow', 'large')]
        self.header = ['fruit', 'color', 'size']

        # create table
        self.createTable()

        # layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tv)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def createTable(self):
        # create the view
        self.tv = QTableView()
        self.tv.setStyleSheet("gridline-color: rgb(191, 191, 191)")

        # set the table model
        tm = MyTableModel(self.tabledata, self.header, self)
        self.tv.setModel(tm)

        # set the minimum size
        self.tv.setMinimumSize(400, 300)

        # hide grid
        self.tv.setShowGrid(True)

        # set the font
        font = QFont("Calibri (Body)", 12)
        self.tv.setFont(font)

        # hide vertical header
        vh = self.tv.verticalHeader()
        vh.setVisible(False)

        # set horizontal header properties
        hh = self.tv.horizontalHeader()
        hh.setStretchLastSection(True)

        # set column width to fit contents
        self.tv.resizeColumnsToContents()

        # set row height
        nrows = len(self.tabledata)
        for row in xrange(nrows):
            self.tv.setRowHeight(row, 18)

        # enable sorting
        self.tv.setSortingEnabled(True)

class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, datain, headerdata, parent=None, *args):
        """ datain: a list of lists
            headerdata: a list of strings
        """
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.arraydata = datain
        self.headerdata = headerdata

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        return QVariant(self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()])

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.headerdata[col])
        return QVariant()

    def sort(self, Ncol, order):
        """Sort table by given column number.
        """
        self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutAboutToBeChanged()"))
        self.arraydata = sorted(self.arraydata, key=operator.itemgetter(Ncol))
        if order == Qt.DescendingOrder:
            self.arraydata.reverse()
        self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutChanged()"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That turned out to be easier than I thought. Simply adding this row makes the selection to be by row instead of cell.

```
self.tv.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
```

Comment: QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows if you haven't loaded QtGui

Answer (score 19):

In PyQt5 `SelectRows` has moved.  The code is now:

```
self.tv.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QTableView.SelectRows)
```

Answer (score 2):

For C++ the answer is

```
tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QTableView::SelectRows);
```